# React native geolocation getCurrentPosition no reponse (android)

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I have read and tested a lot of issues but I still can not get geolocation on Android.

I use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, on iOS everything works fine, but on Android I have no answer to this function, either success or error.

I have installed react-native-permissions to make sure that the user has activated the permissions but it does not change anything because it says that everything is "authorized".

I noticed that it came from GPS of the device. If I activate it manually, everyting works fine. However, I can not find a way to activate it for the user. On iOS, if GPS is not activated, I fall in the error callback and tell user to activate it, but on android, nothing is happennig.

I don't understand why I can't get geolocation only with getCurrentPosition (I have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in manifest).

Here a part of my code:

```
componentDidMount() {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    //do my stuff with position value
  },
  (error) => {
    Permissions.getPermissionStatus('location')
    .then((response) => {
      if (response !== "authorized") {
        Alert.alert(
          "Error",
          "We need to access to your location",
          [
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              onPress: () => {
                // do my stuff
              }, style: 'cancel'
            },
            {
              text: "Open Settings",
              onPress: () => Permissions.openSettings()
            }
          ]
        );
      } else {
        // do my stuff
      }
    });
  },
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 1000 }
);

}
```

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Emulator or device? The emu's geolocation doesn't seem to work when you set the coordinates. I've not been able to get them through to my RN app.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Marina.A Are you inside a batiment ? GPS Localisation can take more than 1 min if it is the case( on android).

Answer (score -1):

You should need to enable **GPS** on android

For enabling location/gps on Android I can recommend this module:

https://github.com/Richou/react-native-android-location-enabler

It is using the standard Android dialog for location:

like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import RNAndroidLocationEnabler from "react-native-android-location-enabler";

export default class index extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLocation();
  }

  onLocationEnablePressed = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      RNAndroidLocationEnabler.promptForEnableLocationIfNeeded({
        interval: 10000,
        fastInterval: 5000,
      })
        .then((data) => {
          this.getLocation();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert("Error " + err.message + ", Code : " + err.code);
        });
    }
  };

  getLocation = () => {
    try {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          //do my stuff with position value
        },
        (error) => {
          Permissions.getPermissionStatus("location").then((response) => {
            if (response !== "authorized") {
              Alert.alert("Error", "We need to access to your location", [
                {
                  text: "Cancel",
                  onPress: () => {
                    // do my stuff
                  },
                  style: "cancel",
                },
                {
                  text: "Open Settings",
                  onPress: () => Permissions.openSettings(),
                },
              ]);
            } else {
              // do my stuff
            }
          });
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 1000 }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      this.onLocationEnablePressed();
    }
  };


}
```

Comment: even if the location service is off, the module throws an exception with `code = 2` showing that `service is unavailable`. the point is module doesnt show anything at all, it doesnt succeed, nor it fails.

Comment: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is depend on GPS. you can handle GPS enable on try-catch exception handling and recursive call of location function

Comment: tnx for the answer, i tried it. not working. the point is i think its RN native codes bug. somehow the same code works in other project but not here.

Comment: @Amas but we have to enable GPS by programmatically on android

Comment: @Amas can you share demo project on the git repo. so I can see what problem you are getting. maybe you got another bug which I did not face